# You would have heard it Riddle?

Tags: riddle

> Hit me once I start crying ,
>
> Hit me again I sleep like a baby .
>
> Touch my neighbors I undergo  metamorphosis ,
>
> Keep hitting them I create time travel.
>
> And I am there where  u all watch.

What  am I ?

> hint : sometimes i am shown as parlleotriangallogram .

Comment: Is the use of "u" instead of "you" important to the puzzle?

Comment: Or "me metamorphosis"?

Comment: @feelinferrety slightly..yes

Comment: I have to admit I'm impressed--the only Google results for parlleotriangallogram take you to this page.

Comment: Google disagrees. :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is

> The play/pause button (like on youtube)

Hit me once I start crying ,

> when you hit play

Hit me again I sleep like a baby .

> when you hit pause

Touch my neighbors I undergo metamorphosis ,

> the next button ???

Keep hitting them I create time travel.

> forward

And I am there where u all watch.

> when you watch a video

Answer (score 11):

It could be a

> digital wrist watch

As,

Hit me once I start crying,

> For verifying the feature of alarm, we can hit specific button to make the watch make sound

Hit me again I sleep like a baby .

> hit the same button to keep it off

Touch my neighbors I undergo me metamorphosis ,

> These can be lights on / change colors feature of few digital watches

Keep hitting them I create time travel.

> Some buttons when kept on hitting, increases minutes, hours, dates, months and years - a kind of time travel (either future or past)

And I am there where u all watch.

> Is of course located on a wrist to watch !

Comment: Probably applies for a phone as well

Answer (score 4):

Is it a:

> Television?

Hit me once I start crying ,

> The power button turns it on, creating sound

Hit me again I sleep like a baby .

> The power button turns it off again

Touch my neighbors I undergo me metamorphosis ,

> A remote control can change the channel, presenting a different series of shapes and sounds to the viewer (alternatively, DVD players, DVR etc. connected to the TV can have much the same effect)

Keep hitting them I create time travel.

> Lots of TV channels have a +1 equivalent, showing the same shows an hour later. (alternatively, DVD players, DVR etc. have skip backward/forward options)

And I am there where u all watch.

> Generally the centrepiece of a lounge/living room, where everyone can see it

Comment: My first thought was a television remote, similar logic. (I don't think this should be more than a comment, though)

Answer (score 4):

It could be

> A video player

Because...

You press once,

> It "cries", as in the speakers play the content (assuming the video contains sound)

You press it again,

> It stops the video and it becomes quiet as a sleeping baby

Touch my neighbors,

> As in the buttons for quality and resolution etc...

Keep on pressing

> It fast forwards, like on YouTube

Comment: This was the answer I was going to put. The only difference I was thinking was for: "Touch my neighbors I undergo me metamorphosis" would be `other videos` and the display plays a different video in the same place, as if it morphed.

Answer (score 1):

You are

> The Snooze Button

Hit me once I start crying ,

> if you hit the snooze button, on some alarm clocks it will play the alarm sound

Hit me again I sleep like a baby .

> sleep = snooze. You hit the snooze button to have the alarm 'sleep' for a few more minutes, before 'waking up' and going off again.

Touch my neighbors I undergo me metamorphosis ,

> The other buttons on the alarm clock can be used to set and change the alarm time

Keep hitting them I create time travel.

> You can also use them to change the time of the clock itself.

And I am there where u all watch.

> a 'watch' is another kind of clock, although not usually one with a snooze button

Answer (score 1):

It's:

> A computer laptop's power button.

Hit me once I start crying,

> You hit it once it starts making a noise

Hit me again I sleep like a baby .

> Hit it again it either goes to sleep or hibernate (as configured)

Touch my neighbors I undergo me metamorphosis ,

> Touch neighboring buttons and you make it undergo metamorphosis

Keep hitting them I create time travel.

> Keep hitting them u create time travel - u could travel to future if you are preparing an article or a report. You can travel to past and recall what u did wrong with your work/game.

And I am there where u all watch.

> And the power button is there where we all watch (near the screen).